# Find missing values between two lists of IDs using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large list of IDs that received a certain status (Ex: status is 'EMAIL SENT'). These should be accompanied by another row with another status (Ex: 'EMAIL OPENED').
I have both lists of IDs, a list of all of those that are EMAIL SENT and a list of all of those IDs that also received EMAIL OPENED. What is the best way, using an SQL query, to find the IDs that have EMAIL SENT but have not received EMAIL OPENED?

The IDs I am searching on are not primary keys, there can be multiple IDs in this table each with its own status.

I had though of using EXISTS but this will just give a T/F. The desired result would be a list of IDs that are found in the larger list of EMAIL SENT but not found in the smaller list of EMAIL OPENED.

Comment: Does sql-server support an EXCEPT clause? select id from table where status = 'SENT' except select id from table where status = 'OPENED'

Comment: Don't think. Write a query and then evaluate it for correctness and efficiency. EXCEPT, outer join, NOT IN - all possible ways of writing the query. And don't ask "best way" questions. "Best" cannot be measured and is generally relative to your situation.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]